# Link the function from one cell to the same cell in another sheet

Tags: excel, function, cell

I am trying to link the function from one cell to the same cell in another sheet.

The idea is that each sheet has different data used in the function. But the functions used are the same and are located in the same cells, so I want to make sure that if I change one function I change them all at the same time.

I hope for either of two solutions:

- having all the function cells linked so no matter what formula I change the others will to.

or

- having one main sheet that lets all the following sheets inherit the main function.

Comment: Do you have sample data? Or just show a sample how data are organized? I don't think a function will be enough but i need to see the sample data.

Comment: If your formula is in `A1` of `Sheet1` ... isn't `=Sheet1!A1` in `Sheet2`'s `A1` working for you?

Comment: The problem with =sheet1!A1 is that it gives me A1s value, and I’m not interested in that, I’m only interested in the function leading to the value. E.g A1 =SUM.IF(U46:U96;">=0";U46:U96).
I would want function A1 in sheet 1, 2, 3 and 4 to have the same formula without having to copy paste every time I make a change in one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the sheets before entering or changing the formulae. BTW `=SUM.IF` is not valid syntax.